# GAE gcloud dev_appserver.py PHP: Failed to read session data: user (path: Memcache)

Tags: php, linux, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I run a local Google Cloud App Engine emulator for my PHP `(runtime: php55)` app. It works, except for PHP sessions. I get the following message:

```
Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: Memcache)
```

I start the app with the following command

```
dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php-cgi ./default
```

So I run using php-cgi. Before this I tried to run with regular php but then I got a WSOD. In a Google Group it was a suggested to use php-cgi which solved that problem for me. But now I still have this problem, that seems to be related to Memcache.

This is on Linux Mint (Ubuntu), and this problem didn't occur on a Windows Machine where I have the same app running in the emulator.

When I install php-memcache, I cannot start the app anymore. When running the above command with php-memcache installed, I get this error:

```
PHPEnvironmentError: The PHP runtime cannot be run with the 
"Memcache" PECL extension installed
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, while struggling with the same problems as you, I found out [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/php-differences) that:

> dev_appserver.py is not supported with the PHP 7.2 runtime. To test your application and run it locally, you must download and install PHP 7.2 and set up a web server.

That being said, with php-cgi & java it seems to be running, with some differences, memcache extension indeed must be disabled in `php.ini`, but the runtime register the `Memcached` class so this should work in both dev & App Engine Env:

```
extension_loaded('memcached') || class_exists('Memcached')
```

Back to your question, I solved the session error by doing this in dev mode:

```
ini_set('session.save_handler', 'files');
ini_set('session.save_path', null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't solve the problem with PHP cgi but I worked around it by writing my own session handler. GAE by default stores the sessions in Memcache with a 'user' session handler. If that for some reason doesn't work you can use my following code to switch your local GAE to a 'files' session handler and store the sessions in a folder:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'localhost') {

    class FileSessionHandler {

        private $savePath;

        function open($savePath, $sessionName) {
            $this->savePath = $savePath;
            if (!is_dir($this->savePath)) {
                mkdir($this->savePath, 0777);
            }

            return true;
        }

        function close() {
            return true;
        }

        function read($id) {
            return (string) @file_get_contents("$this->savePath/sess_$id");
        }

        function write($id, $data) {
            return file_put_contents("$this->savePath/sess_$id", $data) === false ? false : true;
        }

        function destroy($id) {
            $file = "$this->savePath/sess_$id";
            if (file_exists($file)) {
                unlink($file);
            }

            return true;
        }

        function gc($maxlifetime) {
            foreach (glob("$this->savePath/sess_*") as $file) {
                if (filemtime($file) + $maxlifetime < time() && file_exists($file)) {
                    unlink($file);
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

    }

    $handler = new FileSessionHandler();
    session_set_save_handler(
            array($handler, 'open'), array($handler, 'close'), array($handler, 'read'), array($handler, 'write'), array($handler, 'destroy'), array($handler, 'gc')
    );
    session_save_path('[PATH_TO_WRITABLE_DIRECTORY]');

    register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
}

session_start();
```